# customize StageWebView

Tags: apache-flex, windows-8, air, stagewebview

I'm trying to use StageWebView on Windows 8.  Since air doesn't have a special version for windows 8, it will be using the desktop version of stagewebview.  I would like to make the scrollbar bigger so the user can be easier to move the scrollbar.  Any idea how to do this?  Can I do this through css or skinning?

Answer (score 2):

StageWebView for Windows uses the native browser, meaning you are actually getting an instance of IE 10 in your application.
Unfortunately, as far as I know, you cannot change the width or height of the scrollbars in IE, however, you could try using a plugin and see if it does the trick. You can try, for example, http://codevisually.com/jquery-custom-scrollbar-plugin/